# Malleability of homomorphic encryption

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, malleability

El Gamal is a malleable homomorphic encryption system, so is Rabin. Are all homomorphic encryption systems malleable? Or are there any that are not malleable?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you define malleable?

Comment: From Wikipedia - An encryption algorithm is malleable if it is possible for an adversary to transform a ciphertext into another ciphertext which decrypts to a related plaintext.

Comment: Malleable and being (semi-)homomorphic is the almost same functionality, from a different point of view: Malleable usually is used, if that property is a security weakness (and it is more general: it is by definition not limited to the actual group structure). It is called homomorphic, if this functionality is used to achieve some more complex functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer may depend on your exact definitions of "homomorphic" and "malleable", but I'll give it a shot.

Basically, *homomorphic encryption* means that given encryptions $E_k(x)$ and $E_k(y)$ of some values $x$ and $y$, you can obtain an encryption of $x\ast y$ under the same key $k$ from $E_k(x)$ and $E_k(y)$, where $\ast$ is some binary operation, *without* knowledge of the key $k$. Typically, $\ast$ is the usual addition or multiplication on (bounded) integers, but the attack actually works for almost arbitrary operations (namely, there must be a pair $(x,y)$ such that $x\ast y\notin\{x,y\}$): Assume that an attacker knows $x$ and $y$ along with their encryptions $E_k(x)$ and $E_k(y)$. They may then compute $E_k(x)\mathbin{\hat\ast}E_k(y)$, where $\hat\ast$ denotes the "lifted" implementation of $\ast$ on ciphertexts, to obtain a ciphertext $\zeta$. By definition, $\zeta$ decrypts to $x\ast y$, which was assumed different from both $x$ and $y$. Hence, the attacker has obtained a ciphertext ($\zeta$) corresponding to a plaintext they know ($x\ast y$) *but whose ciphertext they haven't observed before*.

Therefore, any homomorphic encryption scheme is malleable.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I am wondering if there is a way to formally prove it. I will use your explanation to come up with a general proof.

Comment: The above is more of an intuition why "homomorphic" *should* generally imply "malleable". If you post the definitions you're using, I will try to come up with a more formal proof (which can't possibly make sense without definitions).

Comment: Your definition of homomorphism is what I am using. For malleable, if an attacker can derive ciphertext c2 from observed ciphertext c1, where plaintext m2 is meaningfully related to plaintext m1 then the encryption scheme is considered malleable

Comment: This is pretty much what I used, except in your case the attacker gets to see only one ciphertext; he can instead use $E_k(x)\mathbin{\hat\ast}E_k(x)$ for some $x$ with $x\ast x\neq x$ as a forged ciphertext.

Comment: In one direction, there is nothing to show: Being homomorphic implies already some meaningful relation (e.g. you can always compute $2 \cdot m,3 \cdot m,...$). And for the other direction: The expression "meaningful relation" is not specific enough to achieve a homomorphic relation between ciphertexts.